# No sound ubuntu 12.04, Tried everything

Tags: 12.04, sound, wubi, alsa

I've tried to find a solution to this but haven't been able to yet.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 installing using wubi installer.

I have no audio. I can see the sound icon on the bar on top and interact with it. 
It doesn't say mute, it seems normal.

```
"Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*
proc/asound/card0/codec#0:Codec: IDT 92HD75B3X5
proc/asound/card0/codec#1:Codec: LSI ID 1040
proc/asound/card1/codec#0:Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
```

Alsa shows all bars full for IDT 92HD75B3X5,

no bars for ATI HDMI.

Please help. I've reinstalled all drivers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-m4
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1
```

Make sure they're at the **end** of the file.